# Qt4 Error: undefined reference to `QWebView::QWebView(QWidget*)' , `QWebView::load(QUrl const&)'

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, vlc, qtwebkit

I am trying to add a browser control in separate dialog box in VLC using Qt4.
I managed to add a menu item in menu bar which open a dialog.

Following is my code:

```
class DialogBrowser : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT
public: 
explicit DialogBrowser(QWidget *parent = 0): QDialog(parent)
{
m_pWebView = new QWebView(this); 
m_pWebView->setGeometry(0,0,1000,900);
m_pWebView->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}   
virtual ~DialogBrowser(){}; 
private:
QWebView* m_pWebView;
};
```

i am using QtWebkit for adding web browser control.
I am getting following error in compilation

```
undefined reference to `QWebView::QWebView(QWidget*)'
undefined reference to `QWebView::load(QUrl const&)'
```

I do not have .pro file for doing QT+=webkit. not resolving error so need some other solution

i have `libQtWebKit.so` file but i am doing cross compilation on Ubuntu for windows, so i need `libQtWebKit.a` file.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Which build system do you use?

Comment: I am using GNU build system and following these instructions https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the webkit header? Either in your header file or your source file, you need to add `#include <QtWebkit>` or `#include <QWebView>`